# Custom validation on Activiti form field

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I need to know how to create a custom validation rule to be applied to a specific field in an Activiti form and how to deploy all the files together to its engine.

Thanks

Comment: What alfresco version are you on ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reusable field level validations (e.g: phone number, zip code, etc), I think the best approach is to register a custom FormType in the engine´s configuration (check item 9.1 on Activiti´s user guide). Custom **FormType** implementations are created by extending **AbstractFormType** and implementing a few methods that converts to/from a String into whatever representation you want to use internally.

Form level validation (i.e., validations that are applied to the form as a whole) I usually use a **TaskListener** attached to the task that listens to the EVENTNAME_COMPLETE event. In this listener you do your validation logic and throw an exception in case something is wrong.

As for "deploying everything together": For the simplest case, you just create a jar with the extra validation classes and put it in your classpath. If you want this code to be deployed with your process then there is no straightforward answer. It is possible, but I think this should be the topic for another question.

Comment: can we have a small chat?

Answer (score 0):

Philippe's answer should give you pretty solid results. Another way to do it without adding JavaScript is to use regex constraints in your model.

For example, if I want my input to be a five digit area code, I might do this:

```
<constraint name="myWorkflow:zipRegex" type="REGEX">
    <parameter name="expression">
        <value>^\d{5}$</value>
    </parameter>
</constraint>
```

Here's a nice tool for building and testing regexs, by the way: https://regex101.com/

In this case, no external files besides the normal bpmn20, model, config-custom, and their context files are eneded and deployment can be done the same way as is typical. Drop the files into their respective class folders (/extension for bpmn, model, and their context file; /web-extension for config-custom and its context) and restart the service. If it's already been deployed and just redeploying, use the workflow console to deploy with the command 'deploy activiti alfresco/extension/myWorkflow.bpmn20.xml'